# Access to AppDelegate methods from NSViewController

Tags: swift, macos, appdelegate, nsviewcontroller

I'm trying to execute a method present in AppDelegate from my NSViewController class.
I tried this line to access to the AppDelegate :

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
```

Without success : Use of unresolved identifier 'UIApplication'.
Tried to import UIKit, doesn't works ... cause it's for IOS ?

PS : It's hard to learn how to develop in swift ... a lot of tutorials are for objective C, and the swifts can also be for IOS ...

Comment: Look at docs for `NSApplication`...anything UI* is iOS.  Your problem is more about platform than language.

Comment: I'm a noob ... would you please make an answer ? I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***NS***ViewController is clearly macOS.

In macOS you get the application delegate with

```
let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

`NSApp` is a shortcut for `NSApplication.shared`

Comment: Weird that NSApplication.shared as! AppDelegate will fail, but NSApp works as expected.

Comment: @Starwave It's not weird. You have to write `NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate `